# Synergy connected fine but mouse doesn't move with two Windows 7 machines

Tags: windows-7, synergy

I configured Synergy correctly enough for it to connect just fine between two machines.  So both log outputs say connected to each other.  Then I move my mouse and it doesn't magically jump to the other PC.  What am I missing here?

- Server machine is windows 7 64bit running as admin
- Client machine is windows 7 32bit running as admin

What's confusing to me is the configure server button where you get to drag and drop and name computers. I thought you only had to write out left and right if using Mac or Linux. I just placed my PCs correctly in the UI the program has and figured it'd know which one is where.

Also in which file/section do I write that? How do I get there? And where is the config file? Don't see one in the programs folder.

My version of Synergy is the latest one just downloaded from the synergy website for Windows 64 bit on the server and 32 bit on the client.

Comment: do you have the screens setup properly? Post your config file.

Comment: Which version of Synergy?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem (I had the screens configured already and earlier it was working for some time).

I turned logging level to Debug in settings, and noticed "DEBUG: locked to screen" messages. After some trial and error I noticed the Scroll Lock LED was lit on the keyboard; **I hit the Scroll Lock key to turn it off and Synergy started working again!** I can move between monitors/machines now. BTW, both machines are multi-monitor. Server is Win7 x64, client is Win8 x86. Synergy ver. 1.4.10 running as service on both.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't tell Synergy which screen to jump to when you move the mouse off the edge of your monitor, nothing will happen (it can't magically know that one of your computers is on the left of the other.)

Here is a simple section for a left/right pair:

```
section: links
    moe:
        right = larry
    larry:
        left = moe
end
```

More advanced options [are available](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/configuration.html).  Don't forget to list each PC in both directions (as above), otherwise you will move your mouse across to one PC but then you'll be unable to move it back again!

Answer (score 1):

Following Ekus' response, I turned on debug logging.  I have a special Logitech mx510 mouse plugged into my Mac which is the server. Turns out that one of the side buttons does a similiar "lock" as the scoll lock he mentioned. The debug log showed "locked by mouse buttonId: 0". I must have accidentally pressed the button. When I pressed the button again, it worked again!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question. We're a Q&A community, not a conventional forum, so answer posts must answer (or attempt to answer) the question—answer posts which fail to do so are subject to deletion. Instead of saying "thanks!", you can [upvote posts](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you find useful once you earn 15 [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation).